# How to hide a particular column in a web grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
<div id="gridContent">
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle:"webGrid",
headerStyle: "header",
alternatingRowStyle:"alt",
selectedRowStyle:"select",
columns:grid.Columns(grid.Column("Name","Name",style:"description"),grid.Column("DomainName","Domain Name",style:"hide"),grid.Column("ClientID","client ID",,style:"hide")</div>
<style type="text/css">
.hide {display:none;}<style>
```

I am trying to hide a column using the above code, but the column header is not hiding. How can I hide the column header?

Comment: The reason people keep adding those spaces to your post is so that the code gets displayed correctly. You can read more about the formatting system at http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

You can have something like that

```
@{

  var grid = new WebGrid(Model);

    @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column(null,null, format: @<input type="hidden" name="IDHidden" value="@item.IDHidden"/>),

                                                             grid.Column("Title", "Title")));

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Nilesh with the help of your answer I solved My self
grid.Column("FriendlyId", style:"hidecol",header:"")
Insted of using like this you have to use Like bellow manner I tried It will work successfully.
grid.Column(format: @&lt;input type="hidden" name="FriendlyId" value="@item.FriendlyId" /&gt;)

Answer (score 1):

its too easy just comment this section.
just like that

```
    @*grid.Column( "null" ,format:@<input type="hidden" name="ID" id="ID"/>),*@

    grid.Column("Description",canSort:true,header: "Description",format: @<span>
        <span id="spanDescription_@item.ID">@item.Description</span> 
        @Html.TextBox("Description"+(int)item.ID,(string)item.Description,new{@style="display:none"})</span>),
```